# Download all files from a pure ftp server with a server limit

Tags: ftp, wget, ftp-client, lftp

I need to download all files from a FTP server but the server has a lookup limitation on 10,000 which complicates things.

I can't use `wget -m ftp://username:password@server-adress` since it will only download the first 10,000 files. I can use `mget` like `mget 20[12]*`, `mget 20[34]*` etc. but it is cumbersome AND some downloads fails without me knowing which ones.

Now I have come across `lftp`. I was getting my hopes up for this command

```
mirror --use-pget=10 --only-missing --no-symlinks
```

But it doesn't download anything, it just outputs

```
To be removed: 0 directories, 70695 files, 0 symlinks
```

Now I am clueless how to actually download all files from a FTP server with a limit

#### EDIT

Now I went ahead and created a script that produces a `missing.txt` with a list of files that I still need to download. How can I use that file to download the files one by one? The list is `\n` delimited.

Comment: 1) Your question is off-topic. 2) If the server won't give you a list of all files, there's nothing you can do about it. Changing FTP client cannot help. All you can do is to guess the names (like your attempt with `mget 20[12]*`) or get the names using other means (not FTP)

Comment: You can also move the already downloaded files (if possible) to a different folder and then repeat the download. Then you can move the files back.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl thanks for your reply. Just out of interest, why is is off-topic? I see downvotes but I have no clue why.

Comment: Your question (at least your original question) is not about programming.

Comment: I partly agree. It just so turned out that programming was the solution but I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

So I went ahead and made a script of all the missing files called `missing.txt`. Then I created a loop to download each file. And now it is actually downloading one by one. The `download.sh` script looks like this

```
#!/bin/bash
HOST='HOSTNAME'
USER='USERNAME'
PASSWD='PASSWORD'

echo open $HOST > ftp.txt
# echo ascii >> ftp.txt
echo user $USER $PASSWD >> ftp.txt
# echo prompt no >> ftp.txt

while read p; do
    echo "get $p"
done <missing.txt >> ftp.txt

echo bye >> ftp.txt
ftp -in < ftp.txt
rm ftp.txt
```

And then it is just a matter of running `./download.sh`.